# OCaml: Bidirectional reference

Tags: ocaml

here is a code snippet I wrote.

```html
    let trans_binop _ =
      let l = trans_exp lexp in

      B.binop_build op l r

    let trans_exp exp =
      match exp with
        | _->
           trans_binop binop
```

The above code is simplified. And these two functions are defined inside one `Module`. The problem is that: the first function needs to refer to the second one, while the second one needs to refer to the first.. **Then it just cannot compile.**

I basically don't want to put one `let` expression into another one, because I think it is not decent logically..

Could any one give me some help on this question? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `and` to declare mutually recursive functions

```
let rec trans_binop _ =
  let l = trans_exp lexp in

  B.binop_build op l r

and trans_exp exp =
  match exp with
    | _->
       trans_binop binop
```

Comment: Thank you Jeffrey. You saved my ass again:)

Answer (score 3):

You have to define your functions as mutually recursive. That means you have to use the keyword `and` in the place of the second `let`. See also https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/labels.html